# Steady Animation?

Tags: objective-c, commitanimations

I am making a iPhone/iPad app with a cursor and music. I am running a timer every beat and moving it like so:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:theLength];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
theCursor.frame = CGRectMake(theX, 0, 6, 320);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However, it seems to start off fast then slow down as it gets to the end. Is there any way to make the animation steady?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the animation curve.  By default it is set to `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`.  Use [setAnimationCurve:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW37) to set it to `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear`.

You should also be aware that that way of animating is deprecated and Apple now recommend using the block-based animation style.